# Limit with jquery number of files are uploaded

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a custom form for uploading image files to a blog. I try to limit with a jquery script the number of files will be uploaded, but without success. What is wrong with this script?

My (simplified) form:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="adverts-form">

    <div class="moxie-shim" id="">
        <input id="" multiple="" accept="" type="file">
    </div>

    <input name="submit" value="Preview" class="adverts-cancel-unload" type="submit">

</form>
```

My jquery script:

```
jQuery(".moxie-shim").children("input").change(function(){
    if(this.files.length>3)
        alert("to many files")
    });
// Prevent submission if limit is exceeded
jQuery(".adverts-form").submit(function(){
    if(this.files.length>3)
        return false;
    });
```

**UPDATE**

Updated the jquery as suggested by @drunkwolf, but images are still uploaded (no limits).

```
jQuery(".adverts-form").submit(function(){
    if(jQuery("#adverts-plupload-upload-ui input")[0].files.length>2){
        alert("nope still to many")
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The second `this` isn't referring to the same thing as the first. On submit you need to check if the input has more then 3 files, not the form. One way to do that is like so:

```
jQuery(".adverts-form").submit(function(){
    if(jQuery('input[type=file]')[0].files.length>2){
        alert("nope still to many")
        return false;
        }
    });
```

Altough the exact implementation would obviously depend on how many inputs you have on the site/form. Click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/65nkm5er/1/) for a working example.

Comment: @amit-soni Sorry! Maybe I do something wrong, but both solutions doesn't work :(. Can you look at the original form? - http://android.info.md/wpadverts/anunturi/adauga

Comment: @lurie try `if(jQuery("#adverts-plupload-upload-ui input")[0].files.length<3){..`

Answer (score 0):

check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pqv5gauz/3/)

```
<div class="moxie-shim" id="">
    <input id="file" multiple="" accept="" type="file">
</div>

<input name="button" value="Preview" class="adverts-cancel-unload" type="submit">

jQuery(".moxie-shim").children("input").change(function(){
    if(this.files.length>3)
        alert("to many files")
    });
// Prevent submission if limit is exceeded
jQuery(".adverts-form").submit(function(){
    if(jQuery("#file")[0].files.length>3)
        return false;
    });
```